# How to display multiple arrows on canvas with multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, html, events, canvas

I am trying to display multiple arrows on canvas, so when after I click it creates completely new arrow. I am a beginner as you can see, thank you for any help or further ideas of how to improve the code!

[image: Arrow image]

```js
var arrowX = -300;
var arrowY = 300;

window.onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    gc = canvas.getContext("2d");

    document.addEventListener("click", mouseClickHandler, false);
    window.setInterval(render, 200);

    arrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
};

function mouseClickHandler(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName.localeCompare("canvas") && event.button == 0) {
        arrowX = event.clientX;
        arrowY = event.clientY;
    }
}

function arrowDown() {
    //makes arrow go down
    if (arrowY < 450) {
        arrowY += 6;
    }
    if (arrowY < 250) {
        arrowY -= 3;
    }
}

function render() {
    gc.clearRect(0, 0, 1500, 500);
    gc.drawImage(arrow, arrowX, arrowY);
    arrowDown();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1500" height="500" style="border:1px solid black;" tabindex="1" onclick="mouseClickHandler(event);">
    <img id="arrow" class="arrow" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/evnjm.png" width="20" height="50" />    
</canvas>
```

Comment: If you want a click Event on the canvas, it's then put it there instead of the document. Also `arrowY=arrowY+=6` is the same as just `arrowY+=6`, which is short for `arrowY = arrowY+6`. Just comments.

Comment: You're going to want to calculate those coords based on `var bc = canvasElement.getBoundingClientRect(); arrowX = event.clientX-bc.left; arrowY = event.clientY-bc.top;`. You're only taking only into account `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`, when canvas positions are really bases on the canvasElement.

Comment: Thanks but I can't seem to make it work, what I want is to have multiple arrows flying down at once, so each click on canvas creates completely new arrow

Answer (score 1):

I had a question very similar to this! Go ahead and try this code, using a constructor:

```
var id = 0;
var arrows = [];
function Arrow(x, y) {
this.id = id++
this.y = y || 0
this.x = x || 0
}
// remove the shape from the array function terminate(id) {
arrows = arrows.filter(arrow => arrow.id !== id)
}
// or add a shape
function spawn() {
arrows.push(new Arrow())
}
function moveAll(){
arrows.forEach(arrow => arrow.y++;)
}
function drawAll(){
arrows.forEach(arrow => /* draw arrow;*/)
}
```

I hope this helped!

Here's the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623439/full-control-of-many-objects-javascript)