# Full control of many objects Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, constructor

I am working on a game in javascript that spawns and terminates shapes. Therefore, I need full control over these shapes that are being spawned. I want to do the following, but I am not sure on how to do it:

- I want to define a constructor `Shape`.
- Then, I want to make a function so that when it is called, it applies to ALL of the `Shape` in existence and being able to change each ones attribute. (For example, I call function `moveAll()` and all of the shapes' `this.y` increments by one.)
- I also want to be able to terminate a specific `Shape` with a function, or add a `Shape` with a function.

My main problem is this:

```
var x = new Shape();
var y = new Shape();
...
```

I don't want to make a million variables. I need a way to make tons of shapes at once and still be able to control each one individually. And if I made an array, how would I control everything individually?

Anything helps, I just need a basis to understand the concept of constructors. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: You may want to continue reading our JavaScript book/articles at least till you get to arrays . If you need more info on constructors - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects should get you decent start... (you probably looking for building list of objects of the same "type", but not really sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an array of shapes:

```
let shapes = []

// this will create 6 shapes
for(let i of [0,1,2,3,4,5]) {
  shapes.push(new Shape())
}
```

If a shape has an `id` you can terminate it:

```
// incrementing id counter
let id = 0

// x and y are optional starting positions
function Shape(x, y) {
  this.id = id++
  this.y = y || 0
  this.x = x || 0
}

// remove the shape from the array
function terminate(id) {
  shapes = shapes.filter(shape => shape.id !== id)
}

// or add a shape
function spawn() {
  shapes.push(new Shape())
}
```

Now you have your shapes.

The simplest way to move all shapes would be something like this:

```
function moveAll() {
  shapes.forEach(shape => shape.y++)
}
```

Runtime for this will increase as the number of shapes increase.

## updated `moveAll`, per request

```
function moveAll() {
  shapes.forEach(shape => {
    if(shape.type === true) {
      shape.y++
    } else {
      shape.y--
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: in moveAll(), you need to change "shape" to "shapes", or else the name is not consistent

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi no I don't think so. It's iterating over each "shape" in the "shapes" array.

Comment: Then shouldn't it be capitalized?

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi no. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control.

Comment: @AssafiCohen-Arazi I could rename `shape` in the callback as `foo`, and it would still work.

Comment: One more thing. For the moveAll(), I need it so it detects the shape.type, so if shape.type is "true", then y++, and if it is "false", then y--.